# DataTable with JS Source

Tags: javascript, datatables, opayo, sdata

I'm trying to generate some data with Sage Sdata using javascript and after that handle that data with datatables plugin but I'm getting error:

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

```
if(aNode2)
{
    resultTextData += '[';
    resultTextData += "'" + aNode1.nodeValue + "'";
    resultTextData += ',';
    resultTextData += "'" +  aNode2.nodeValue + "'";
    resultTextData += ',';
    resultTextData += "'" + aNode3.nodeValue + "'";
    resultTextData += ']';
    resultTextData += ',';
}

var dataSet =   resultTextData ;

console.log(dataSet);

$('#example').dataTable({
    "data": dataSet,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "aDataSort": [ 0, 1 ] },
        { "aDataSort": [ 1, 0 ] },
        { "aDataSort": [ 2, 3 ] }
    ]

});
```

Answer (score 0):

the `data` option doesn't not accept string inputs. See https://datatables.net/reference/option/data

Answer (score 0):

DataTables support loading from json-encoded string.
Here is Example of converting XML result to array.

```
function FormatDataByIolist($data,$IOlist) {
    $returnAray = array();
    $RecordCount = count($data);
    for($i = 0; $i < $RecordCount; $i++) { 
        $tmpSingleRow = array();
        foreach($IOlist as $colName) {
            $columVal = (string)$data[$i]->$colName;
            $tmpSingleRow[$colName] = $columVal;
        }
        array_push($returnAray,$tmpSingleRow);
        unset($tmpSingleRow);
    }
    return $returnAray;
}
```

After it you need to convert array to json_encoded string that DataTable can understand.

```
$formatted = '{ "data": '.json_encode($returnAray).'}';
```

After writing this in backend you need to add following row in your datatable definition

```
"ajax": "your.php?action=getJson"
```

your.php?action=getJson Method should be GET and should return formatted json-string ( as shown ).

I thnik, this repository will help you to work with SData. ( It is model for working with SData )
https://github.com/AramKocharyan/Sage-SData